# Help me connect to internet using wsl2 in windows 11

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I downloaded Ubuntu 20.40 TLS which is using wsl2. And when I use any command that uses the internet it shuts internet in my pc. I can not connect to internet with any other application either.

So I tried many things to solve it.

Like I changed the dns in the resolv.conf file to 8.8.8.8 and it keeps overwriting it on starting the wsl.

Then I configured the wsl.conf to stop generating it but then it removes it on start even when I create it manually

As a last resort I used chartti +i command to make it permanent

But still this persists. The moment I use ping or apt update or install the internet stops. Please help me

Comment: What is the `ls -la /etc/resolv.conf` output? Maybe it is just a symbolic link to the 
 `../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

Comment: @K-att- Under WSL, it's usually a symlink to the `/mnt/wsl/resolv.conf` that is created by WSL's `init`.

Comment: And Welcome to the Unix & Linux Stack, @Eden.  Normally I answer questions WSL questions here on this site, but in your case, I think I would recommend deleting this and reposting it on Super User.  I believe you are more likely to find a solution there, since the expertise here is more (obviously) Unix & Linux specialized.  As you've said, your problem seems to extend to Windows once "triggered" by the WSL issue.  Also, are you on a VPN?  Corporate or University network?  Anything more that you can add to your question would be great - Thanks!

Comment: The quick resolve is the same. Delete the /etc/resolv.conf link and create a new file instead of it.

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity To follow up on what terdon said, I used to do that before (on Stack Overflow), and the mod there was much more clear - Flagging for migration should only be done for questions with existing answers that should also be migrated.  Otherwise, it's just a waste of mod time.  Terdon's just too nice to say that ;-).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Fair enough :), true that's better for OP also. From now on that would be my advice. Would this subject deserve a meta question?

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity It might, if there's not one already, but a quick search for "migrate" on meta.unix.stackexchange.com came across [this](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4851/432493) pretty quickly.  Not the *exact* same thing, I know.  Or maybe [this question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136/migrating-to-other-se-sites) deserves an updated answer.